# How to make a custom BASH function to cd into a certain directory with autocomplete

Tags: bash, function

I have my projects in a `~/Documents/EP_example_project` naming scheme. They all live under `~/Documents`.

I would like to create a bash-function that allows me to cd into a project-directory from whereever I am on the system; with autocomplete. Like so:

```
cdp E<tab>
# ... EAP_example_additional_project EP_example_project
P<tab>
# prompt now says:
cdp EP_example_project<enter>
# ... And I am in the project-directory.
```

That would be a bit easier then typing `cd ~/Do<tab>EP<tab>` everytime.

I do know the basics about creating a simple function, but cannot find how to add tab-autocompletion to that.

NOTE: while above reasoning makes little sense: the additional ~/Do is not *that* much overhead, it is the additional things I can do in such a function, like print the contents of a certain file if found (.birdseye), list the projects contents, last accessed dates and so on, that make this more interesting in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider [`CDPATH`](http://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/cdpath/). You can `export CDPATH=~/Documents` to have all the directories under ~/Documents added for autocompletion. You can have a function or alias for this export command and set & unset `CDPATH` as and when you need.
Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be really helpful if someone could create an example function for this use case

Answer (score 1):

Bash have built-in support for what you are asking

```
  CDPATH The search path for the cd command.  This is  a  colon-separated
         list  of  directories  in  which the shell looks for destination
         directories specified by the cd  command.   A  sample  value  is
         ".:~:/usr".
```

Add the path to the `CDPATH` variable and the `cd` command will automatically search the content of that variable whenever you try to change directory, regardless of current path.

Answer (score 0):

If your autocomplete has only one option, you can use `*` inside a script where you would use  <kbd>tab</kbd> in command line.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the examples inside /etc/bash_completion.d It is possible what you are trying to do.