# cd alias for moving between parallel directory structures

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let's say I have the following directory structures (variable is the `z` or `y` or `x` or `w` directories):

```
/a/b/c/d/e/z/f/g/h/i/j/k
/a/b/c/d/e/y/f/g/h/i/j/k
/a/b/c/d/e/x/f/g/h/i/j/k
/a/b/c/d/e/w/f/g/h/i/j/k
```

How would I write an alias for the `cd` command (in bash) so that when I am in

```
/a/b/c/d/e/w/f/g/h or in
/a/b/c/d/e/w/f/g/h/i/j or in
/a/b/c/d/e/w/f/g/h/i/j/k
```

and type:

```
cd z
```

it would **respectively** take me in

```
/a/b/c/d/e/z/f/g/h or in
/a/b/c/d/e/z/f/g/h/i/j or in
/a/b/c/d/e/z/f/g/h/i/j/k
```

if I type:

```
cd y
```

it would **respectively** take me in

```
/a/b/c/d/e/y/f/g/h or in
/a/b/c/d/e/y/f/g/h/i/j or in
/a/b/c/d/e/y/f/g/h/i/j/k
```

of course if I type:

```
cd w
```

it should leave me where I am (already there).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28595192/258523) has some answers that may be helpful for you here.

Comment: Also maybe https://github.com/junegunn/fzf .

Comment: Also useful: http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/#WCD_ANCHOR

Comment: Aliases can't do parameter substitution. You need to use a function.

Comment: @Barmar ok give me a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's probably easiest to use a *function*:

```
mycd() {
  cd "/a/b/c/d/e/$1/${PWD#/a/b/c/d/e/*/}"
}
```

put that into your `~/.bashrc` (or another file that you source with something like `. mycd.bash`), and use `mycd x`

Comment: Don't forget doublequotes around the variables.

Comment: I was expecting something more parameterizable as I have 100 such directory structures and I dont want to create 100 functions.

Comment: @gaitat then you need to specify your problem better